# Dump of GAFE Admin settings?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

For an instance of GAFE, is it possible to programmatically do a dump of the complete configuration, capturing all of the settings available via the Admin console?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: I think this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/) can help you even though it's your question is unclear. The Google Apps Admin Settings API allows administrators of Google Apps domains to retrieve and change the settings of their domains in the form of Google Data API feeds. The [Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/) can allow you to manage these categories of domain settings like General, Account, Appearance, Verification, and etc. Just read more on the documents for more information.

Comment: Thanks - I am indeed looking for something to dump the full configuration via an API.  However, the published APIs seem to offer a very limited view of all of the available configuration settings (ie. you query for a very specific value that is a small subset of the whole).  Ideally, the whole configuration would be contained within a json document or something similar.  Thanks for responding and sorry if I wasn't clearer in my initial query.